# Problems building UNode and LNode defined in FGL Data.Graph.Inductive.Graph

Tags: haskell, graph

I'm trying to learn to use FGL.

I don't understand why I can't use `UNode`, `LNode`, `LEdge` and `UEdge`. The types seems unknown to ghci, although when I type `:t mkGraph` it explicitely uses them.

```
λ: import Data.Graph.Inductive.Graph
λ: :t UNode

<interactive>:1:1: Not in scope: data constructor `UNode'
λ: :t LNode

<interactive>:1:1: Not in scope: data constructor `LNode'
λ: :t mkGraph
mkGraph :: Graph gr => [LNode a] -> [LEdge b] -> gr a b
```

What have I forgotten to do ?

I'm trying to create UNode and LNode from Int, and cannot figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UNode` and `LNode` already live at the type level, so asking for their type is a bit strange. Perhaps you want to know their kind, instead, in which case you can use `:k[ind]` instead of `:t[ype]`.

```
Prelude Data.Graph.Inductive.Graph> :k UNode
UNode :: *
Prelude Data.Graph.Inductive.Graph> :k LNode
LNode :: * -> *
```

Or perhaps you want to know how to build one of them, in which case you can use `:i[nfo]` to find out more:

```
Prelude Data.Graph.Inductive.Graph> :i UNode
type UNode = LNode ()   -- Defined in ‘Data.Graph.Inductive.Graph’
Prelude Data.Graph.Inductive.Graph> :i LNode
type LNode a = (Node, a)
    -- Defined in ‘Data.Graph.Inductive.Graph’
Prelude Data.Graph.Inductive.Graph> :i Node
type Node = Int     -- Defined in ‘Data.Graph.Inductive.Graph’
Prelude Data.Graph.Inductive.Graph> :i (,)
data (,) a b = (,) a b  -- Defined in ‘GHC.Tuple’
-- [editor's note: many instances snipped here]
```

And now we finally know how to build a `UNode`, if a bit painstakingly:

```
Prelude Data.Graph.Inductive.Graph> (32, ()) :: UNode
(32,())
```